# How to sum a variable by groups

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, aggregation

So, I have a sample data

```
structure(list(Conversation = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), ID.Number = c("ID 11", "ID 11", "ID 11", "ID 11", 
"ID 11", "ID 11", "ID 14", "ID 14", "ID 14", "ID 14", "ID 14", 
"ID 14"), Swear.word = c(0L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 3L, 
1L, 0L, 4L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -12L))
```

And, I am trying to have a result that looks like

```
structure(list(IDNumber = c(11L, 14L), Convo1 = 2:1, Convo2 = c(7L, 4L), Convo3 = c(0L, 4L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

So, basically, I am trying to see swear words usage (sum of the word usage) by conversation type (convo#) for each participant.

How can I do this using R?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try this `tidyverse` approach. I have used the data shared as `A`. You can use `pivot_wider()` in one code shot to obtain the desired result. Here the code:

```
library(tidyverse)
#Code
New <- A %>% mutate(Conversation=paste0('Conv.',Conversation)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Conversation,values_from=Swear.word,values_fn = sum)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 4
  ID.Number Conv.1 Conv.2 Conv.3
  <chr>      <int>  <int>  <int>
1 ID 11          2      7      0
2 ID 14          1      4      4
```

And an optimal code shot can be (Many thanks and credit to **@starja**):

```
#Code 2
Newdf <- A %>% pivot_wider(names_from = Conversation,
                  values_from=Swear.word,
                  values_fn = sum,names_prefix='Conv.')
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 4
  ID.Number Conv.1 Conv.2 Conv.3
  <chr>      <int>  <int>  <int>
1 ID 11          2      7      0
2 ID 14          1      4      4
```

Comment: Smart use of `values_fn`! To only use `pivot_wider`, you could use `names_prefix`

Comment: @starja Great advice, let me add that piece with credit to you!

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
library(tidverse)


df <- x %>%
    group_by(ID.Number, Conversation) %>%
    summarize(
        total = sum(Swear.word, na.rm = TRUE)
    ) %>%
    spread(Conversation, total) %>%
    magrittr::set_colnames(c("IDNumber","Convo1","Convo2", "Convo3"))
df
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach with `dplyr`, `tidyr` and `stringr`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)

data %>% 
  mutate(ID.Number = as.integer(str_extract(ID.Number, "\\d+"))) %>% 
  group_by(ID.Number, Conversation) %>% 
  summarise(count = sum(Swear.word)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(
    id_cols = ID.Number,
    names_from = Conversation,
    values_from = count,
    names_prefix = "Convo"
  ) %>% 
  rename(IDNumber = ID.Number)
# A tibble: 2 x 4
# Groups:   IDNumber [2]
  IDNumber Convo1 Convo2 Convo3
     <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>
1       11      2      7      0
2       14      1      4      4
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `xtabs` from `base R`

```
xtabs(Swear.word ~ ID.Number + Conversation, df1)
#        Conversation
#ID.Number 1 2 3
#    ID 11 2 7 0
#    ID 14 1 4 4
```

---

Or using `dcast` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(df1), ID.Number ~ paste0('Conv.', Conversation), 
     value.var = 'Swear.word', sum)
#   ID.Number Conv.1 Conv.2 Conv.3
#1:     ID 11      2      7      0
#2:     ID 14      1      4      4
```